# Tableau Level of Detail Calculation

Tags: greatest-n-per-group, tableau-api, calculated-field, level-of-detail

I am working on building a [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/) dashboard and just recently learned about the new Level-of-Detail calculations released in Tableau v9. The raw data is structured as follows:

```
User      Workflow Step      Time Spent in Workflow Step
1         a                  12
1         b                  9
1         c                  2
2         a                  7
2         b                  16
2         c                  4
3         a                  23
3         b                  1
3         c                  7
```

I am building a Tableau Text Table. For each user (User Dimension is placed in the Rows section) I want to display the workflow step with the maximum time spent by the user (User 1 = a, User 2 = b, etc). I am new to LoD calculations and can't figure out how to get this to work.

I have tried the following LoD calculation:

```
If [Time Spent in Workflow Step] = {Max([Time Spent in Workflow Step])} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

When I pull in workflow step as a dimension, and use the calculation above as a filter (set equal to 1), I only get the single user with the longest time spent.

How do I make this calculation on a per-user level?

Answer (score 7):

You are very close. You need to modify your calculation like so:

```
[Time Spent in Workflow Step] = { FIXED [User]: MAX([Time Spent in Workflow Step])}
```

You need to specify the actual level of detail, in this case it is `[User]`.

Additionally, you do not need the `IF` statement. The calculation above will return a Boolean result (True/False). Simply place that in the filter card and set to `TRUE`.

[image]